# Изменить атрибут динамически добавляемого элемента

Tags: javascript

Есть форма на которой по нажатию кнопки добавляется `input` со всеми `options`, Изначально уже присутствующий на странице. Что бы не писать много кода решил просто его скопировать так :

```
var select = document.getElementById('select_edu');
var clone = select.cloneNode(true);
maindiv.appendChild(clone);
```

Как изменить атрибут `name` у `clone` что бы новый `input` отличался от первого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clone.setAttribute("name","val");
```